# Vuetify - different behaviour of examples in local project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I would like to use vuetify's pre-made layout and customize it. I copy whole component of this layout:

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/examples/layouts/complex/

As you can see, right drawer push toolbar to right side:

[image]

But in my project it behaves different, it's showing on top of the page.

[image]

Can you tell me what could be wrong? I have new project with just installed dependencies. Vuetify I added with vue cli like this: `vue add vuetify`

Comment: have you clicked on it? clicking on it gives a similar look. Please share your code

Comment: @depperm I clicked only on sandwich button in both cases and gives different look. As I said I only copy pre-maded layout from page, and replace whole app.vue component https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/docs/src/layouts/layouts/demos/complex.vue

Comment: I understand where the vuetify code is, did you only copy? did you make any changes? if you answered no to the first and yes to the second, you should share your code

Comment: @depperm yes, only copy no changes

Comment: @depperm I tried recreate project and instead dart I used node sass and now it works. Do you think it could be problem with dart?

Comment: I have not used dart with vuetify before, it is possible